# varnishadm remove configuration

Tags: varnish

Can I remove configurations that I've loaded in varnish?

I have:

```
>varnishadm -T 127.0.0.1:6082 vcl.list
available       0 boot
available       0 8080
available       0 8081
available       0 8080b
available       0 8080c
available       0 8081a
available       0 8081b
available       0 8081c
active         21 8081d
```

If I try to overwrite a configuration I get "error code 106"

```
>varnishadm -T 127.0.0.1:6082 vcl.load 8081a /etc/varnish/8081.vcl

Command failed with error code 106
```

Can I remove the configurations in the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your tried vcl.discard ?

> varnishadm -T 127.0.0.1:6082 vcl.discard 8081a

Answer (score 0):

You need to add all the server references in the new vcl as well.

Check this out: I think this might be related to this:
https://serverfault.com/questions/126942/varnish-vcl-reload-fails-after-adding-second-backend